# Como interceptar apenas os métodos públicos de um managed bean?

Tags: java, java-ee, ejb

Se você tiver um bean gerenciado (anotação @ManagedBean), como seria possível interceptar apenas os métodos públicos deste bean?

A motivação para isso seria o seguinte, suponha que você tenha um bean *ControllerBean* que pode ser acessado de uma página xhtml. Mas, você queria que quando qualquer método público desse bean fosse acessado, ele passasse por um outro método antes que verificaria se o usuário tem permissão para acessar aquela área ou não. Caso não tenha, aquela área não seria acessada.

Como podemos fazer isso? Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo funcional?

Comment: De uma olhada em Interceptors, acredito que atenda a sua necessidade

Comment: Não sei se interceptar os métodos é uma solução adequada. O que você faria nesse método caso o usuário não tivesse acesso? Retornaria `null`? Lançaria uma exceção? Isso iria quebrar a página. O que você pode fazer é mudar a visibilidade dos elementos da página através da tag `rendered` de acordo com as permissões do usuário. Eu fiz isso em um sistema criando uma função personalizada que consulta no Spring Security para ver se o usuário ter uma determinada permissão. Isso permite controlar os acessos de uma forma bem granular e melhora a usabilidade, pois o usuário só vê aquilo que pode usar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [Interceptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkeed.html). O Problema é que eles, até onde sei, não funcionam com @ManagedBeans, apenas com beans através de CDI e EJB. 
Oque pode ser feito neste caso é mudar seu bean para @Named ao invés de @ManagedBean

Segue um exemplo muito claro e simples de como trabalhar com interceptors:
https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/cdi/interceptors

Abraços.